# Is there a way to find the time between 2 dates after subtracting in excel?

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula

I am given this task to complete

"What is the average time for a project to go to 3-Offered per year for the years 2016, 2017, and 2018?  Use the formula # Days = [Date Offered] - [Start Date].
Only projects where [Project Template] = "Pre-Approval" will have an offered date, no need to include Fast Track projects in the data."

my current function I am trying to use is
`=AVERAGE(IF((B:B="Pre-Approval")*(C:C="3-Offered")*(YEAR(D:D)=2016),E:E-D:D))` but I am getting the #VALUE! and I'm not sure why.

I will link a screenshot of some of the data used for this task.

[Column D is the start date and Column E is the Offered Date]

[image: DataSheet]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier if you break down the problem into smaller pieces.

First, I would separate the years from the offered date. On a different column, e.g. `Year`, I would apply `=YEAR()` for every item in your `Offered Date` column.

Second, I would take another column, call it `Diff`, and apply `=OfferedDate-StartDate`.

Then, for each individual year I would apply `=AVERAGEIFS(diff_column_range, year_column_range, "3-Offered", year_column, required_year)`

I have an example for you here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhMbe-MPmuFCggjutWepn-QtMri4?e=CxpTCW

Let me know if this works for you.

Cheers!

Comment: I am still getting an #VALUE! for some reason but I think this task wants me to only use one function and use different functions together like averageifs.

Comment: Perhaps you should recheck the format of the columns that contain the dates and the error message. As for only using only one function using my example, if we replace `C2:C5-D2:D5` with the `diff_column_range` e.g. not have a separate column for it, you cannot apply "conditions". If we use `(C2:C5-D2:D5)` this range exists without the context of your `Project Status`, which is why you cannot apply those conditions. At least not with the solution I suggested.